# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}ne^{nz}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to see for what values of z the series $\sum_{n=0}e^{nz}$ and $\sum_{n=0}ne^{nz}$ converges and to find the sum in each case. For the first, it is a geometric series and will converge if |$e^{z}$|<$1$ i.e |$e^{x}$|<1 which is true for all $x<0$, and the sum in this case will be $\frac 1 {1-e^z}$. Please tell me if it is true, Also what can be done for the second series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can forget about $e^z$ and just put $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^n$. 
The first is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$.

Take the derivative of this, then you will be able to get the second.

Comment: Is my solution to the first series correct? also the points of convergence for both the series remain same by differentiating?